# I want to @yield or @include one laravel blade template with another by AJAX, how is it possible?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Is it possible to @yield or @include one blade view file with another blade by AJAX?

Comment: Consider using Vue.js or other front end framework or just vanilla JS to load HTML into the page after loaded in the browser. Blade is server side, JS is client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, make a ajax call to a controller, and from there, return a view rendered.

JS:

```
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "route-to-ajax-call",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:
            {
                param1:param1,
                param2:param2
            },
            success: function (res)
            {
                $('#div').html(res.data);
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
```

Controller:

```
public function returnAjax(Request $request);{
    $parameter1 = $request->param1;

    $view = View::make('route-to-your-view', ['parameter1' => $parameter1]);

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $view]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load HTML into your page using AJAX, but this has not much to do with Blade since Blade renders on the server side.

Using jQuery's `.load()`:

```
<script>
    $('#targetDiv').load({{ url('/route/that/returns/the/html') }})
</script>
```